# Auto fill cells in excel from drop down list

Tags: excel, list, dropdown, auto-populate

I just want to know how to autofill all cell if I select value from 1 cell using drop down box. Suppose in 1st cell of the row I will select "Yes", then all the 5 adjacent cell of that row will also show "Yes". ther is data validation activated in all cell, but i dont need to select it each time.

Comment: SO is best for very concrete answers to specific programming related issues. You should at least try something yourself and provide a minimal code example of the things you are trying to achieve. Check the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdown is in A1 then just make B1 be:

```
=A1
```

so it shows whatever is in cell A1

Comment: Yes, i know that. but the thing is, the others cells also have data validation with drop down list. there should be option so that if any one want it "No" then he can change that. but primarily it will auto populate.